# IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, windows, permissions, python-idle

```
products = {} 
fi=open("prod_file.txt", "r") 
for line in fi:
        L = line.rstrip().split(":")
        products[L[0]] = {"desc" : L[1], "price" : L[2], "stock" : int(L[3]), "reorder" : int(L[4]), "target" : int(L[5])} 
fi.close()
```

this part of code works at school but not at my house.  i am using a simple text file with different values in it. I know that the ordinal numbers start at 0 but it is still giving me this error. I have researched it and there still isnt an answer.  could it be linked to this error window i get?

> "Unable to update Recent Files list: [Errno 13] Permission denied:
>   'C:\Users\Ben\.idlerc\recent-files.lst' ".

please help
I am using version 3.3.2
here is the text file i am using(prod_file.txt):

```
93126793:Knife:1:456:100:500
69584930:Pear:0.25:300:100:900
96865460:AAA Battery 10 Pack:10:508:100:150
68488550:Flip Phone:99.99:12:50:100
45637285:Apple:0.5:255:100:1100
12546732:Banana:0.4:432:100:1000
55993647:Plate:1.99:46:100:170
76038280:Fork:1:546:100:500
14054310:Phone:70.50:5:50:70
25226393:Laptop:40:0:50:100
07165122:Firework:27.5:456:100:200
13566135:AA Battery 10 Pack:13:0:100:200
28963264:Spork:1:555:100:200
06359492:Spoon:1:4656:100:400
15025630:Bowl:1.99:45:100:150
```

Comment: I tried to run your algorithm in my computer and it worked just fine. I believe the "Permission denied" error might be the cause. Have you tried to move the recent-files.lst to a different folder (for backup) and let IDLE create a new one?

Comment: What is the output of the command `icacls C:\Users\Ben\.idlerc\recent-files.lst`?

Comment: I have let idle create a new recent-files list, however i am still getting the same error

Comment: `IndexError` could be raised if one of the lines in your input file is missing a field. The data you've posted has no missing fields, and your code runs without error for me. Are you certain that the sample data is _complete_ and  _exactly_ the same as the data that you are using. It might also be helpful if you posted the exception and traceback. AFAICT the permission error is unrelated.

Comment: To make sure the issue is not related to the algorithm itself, you could try to run it directly from the command line using: <path to python>/python.exe <yourcode.py>

Comment: The IndexError comes from python.exe and should have nothing to do with IDLE.  Put `print(line, L)` before the `products...` line to see which line is causing the exception and what the split result is.  The Recent Files messages comes from IDLE and has nothing to do with the IndexError.  The error messages is slightly improved in current 3.4 and 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

Try running python with admin.
If it still doesn't work maybe it's your version of python not being the same as school's.